# Dynamically calculating start and end dates of records for each ID using R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataset of guests boarding (each row) in a hotel having the following variables: Guest_ID, checkin_date and boarding_days,for each Guest_ID's record, we can naively calculate a temporary checkout_date and checkin_date as follows:

```
temp_checkout_date = checkin_date + boarding_days - 1

temp_checkin_date = checkin_date
```

However, we would like to create new records for each unique guest's boarding having the variables "*new_checkin_date*" and "*new_checkout_date*" such that there is no overlap in each guest's boarding record i.e., for each guest a boarding record (row), can only start 1 day after the previous row has ended and therefore the `(lag(temp_checkout_date) > checkin_date)`.

If there is no overlap, then the *new_checkin_date* and *new_checkout_date* are simply calculated as mentioned before in "temporary" calculations.

However, if there is an overlap in a guest's record, i.e., the date of the previous *temp_checkout_date* >= current row's *checkin_date*, then set the current `new_checkin_date =  lag(temp_checkout_date, 1) + 1`, else retain value of the current row's checkin_date.

Then dynamically calculate the new_checkout_date based on the updated new_checkin_date as: `new_checkout_date = new_checkin_date + boarding_days - 1`.

Repeat this procedure for every row of a Guest_ID.

Here is sample data:

```
data_df <- structure(list(Guest_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2), checkin_date = structure(c(17567, 17602, 17644,17707, 17828, 17878, 17927, 17991, 18037, 18137, 18241, 18345,                                                                        18464, 18563, 18667), class = "Date"), boarding_days = c(70,                                                                                                                             50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this yields your wanted result.

- We `group_by(Guest_ID)` to  do the calculations with each guest separately;
- Then, we make sure the `checkin_date` is in crescent order;
- Then, we create the (temp) `checkout_date`, use it to create the - `new_checkin_date`, based on your condition, and lastly, create the `new_checkout_date`.
- You can later drop the temporary columns if you want with `select()`.

```
library(dplyr)

data_df %>%
  group_by(Guest_ID) %>%
  arrange(checkin_date) %>%
  mutate(checkout_date = checkin_date + boarding_days - 1,
         new_checkin_date = case_when(lag(checkout_date) >= checkin_date ~ lag(checkout_date) + 1,
                                      TRUE ~ checkin_date),
         new_checkout_date = new_checkin_date + boarding_days - 1) %>%
  select(-c(checkin_date, checkout_date))
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, your code looks great! The only place that need updating is with the creation of the new_checkin_date = case_when(lag(checkout_date) > checkin_date. We want this condition temp_checkout_date >= current row's checkin_date. See for instance row 7 in results, the previous checkout date is equal to the current checkin date, hence we want the new_checkin date to also be  the value of the previous checkout + 1.

Comment: Ok, I changed that `>` to a `>=`!